# Show that for any sequence $\{γ_k\}$ convergent to zero, there exists a sequence $\{x(γ_k)\}$ which tends to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following problem

$$\text{minimize}\quad x\quad\text{s.t}\quad  x^2\geq 0 \quad \text{and}\quad x+1\geq0$$

The optimal solution is $x=-1$

Define the (primal) logarithmic barrier $B(x, γ)$ for this problem and find the local minima of
$B$. Also, show that for any sequence $\{γ_k\}$ convergent to zero, there exists a sequence $\{x(γ_k)\}$
which tends to $0$.

My try:

I'm not sure if my next proof is formal enough. Any suggestions would be great!

Let $$B(x, γ) = x-γ\log(x^2)-γ\log(x+1)$$

Let's find its local minima

$$\nabla_xB(x,γ)=1-2γ/x-γ/x-1=_{set}0$$

Now, solving for $x$ we got that

$$ x = \frac{-1+3γ\pm\sqrt{9c^2-2c+1}}{2}$$

Then, when $γ\longrightarrow 0\quad$ we got that $\quad x \longrightarrow 0\quad $ or $\quad x\longrightarrow -1$

We know that the minimum is $x=-1$.

I'm not sure on how to prove that for any sequence $\{γ_k\}$ convergent to zero, there exists a sequence $\{x(γ_k)\}$